What is the relationship between properties defined in spring-kafka and spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka?
I've inherited an app uses the functionality from spring-kafka (@KafkaListener) and also spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka.
The documentation on the properties for spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka is quite good.
And I can see the documentation here for the spring-kafka properties.
What is not clear is how the spring-cloud kafka binder inherits the spring kafka properties.
If I have common properties can I set them at the spring-kafka level and have them inherited by the kafka binder as well? How does that work?


If I have common properties can I set them at the spring-kafka level and have them inherited by the kafka binder as well?

That's essentially what happens there:
/**
 * @ConfigurationProperties is declared on the @Bean method for Spring Boot to ignore
 * constructor binding on KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties. If constructor binding is
 * used, it ignores all the JavaBeans style properties when generating configuration metadata.
 *
 * See the following issues for more details:
 *
 * https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2640
 * https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/34031
 *
 * @param kafkaProperties Spring Kafka properties autoconfigured by Spring Boot
 */
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder")
KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties configurationProperties(
        KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
    return new KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties(kafkaProperties);
}

And further down the code flow:
private Map<String, Object> getConfigurationWithBootstrapServer(
        Map<String, Object> configuration, String bootstrapServersConfig) {
    final String kafkaConnectionString = getKafkaConnectionString();
    if (ObjectUtils.isEmpty(configuration.get(bootstrapServersConfig)) ||
            !kafkaConnectionString.equals("localhost:9092")) {
        configuration.put(bootstrapServersConfig, kafkaConnectionString);
    }
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(configuration);
}

So, indeed original properties comes from Spring Boot auto-configuration, but itself. The rest is just supplement Spring Cloud Stream specific.
